# Copying the Active Directory Address from a Nautilus Window

Tags: nautilus

Is this possible?  For example, if I'm in `~/Folder1/Folder2`, is there a way for me to copy to the clipboard the text string `~/Folder1/Folder2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you are too lazy to perform all the steps Gilles outlined you could install the following Nautilus script to copy the path of the active directory with a hotkey:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Copy current directory to clipboard
# Dependencies: xclip

echo "$PWD" | xclip -selection c
```

For installation instructions and a tutorial on how to set up a key binding for your script please check out [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236414/how-can-i-install-a-nautilus-script) over at Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to focus a widget to edit the current directory, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the path and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel.

If you right-click on an item, use the “Copy” menu entry, and paste into a text box, that pastes the path to the file.

With Nautilus 3.4.2, you can right-click on an item the button bar at the top that shows the path to the current directory and use the “Copy” menu entry.